# Derivative of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Lets say  f is probability funktion to cdf F.

I want to compute $$lim_{ \Delta t \rightarrow 0+}\frac{ P( t<X<t +\Delta t )}{\Delta t}  $$

I should get $f(t) $. How do I get to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lim_{ \Delta t \rightarrow 0+}\frac{ P( t<X<t +\Delta t )}{\Delta t} = \lim_{ \Delta t \rightarrow 0+}\frac{ P(X < t + \Delta t) - P ( X \leq t )}{\Delta t} $$
$$ = \lim_{ \Delta t \rightarrow 0+}\frac{ F( t + \Delta t ) - F( t )}{\Delta t} = F'(t) = f(t) $$

Comment: Why is it important to go to 0 from right?

Comment: @Sarah : Because, by definition, $ F $ is non-decreasing, and eveywhere right-continous, so the limite from right of $ t $ always exists. Therefore, $ \lim_{ \Delta t \to 0^+ } $ always exists. Neverthless, since $ F $ is not usually left - continuous, we don't require that $ \lim_{ \Delta t \to 0^- } $ exists.

Comment: Why can F be not left continous?

Comment: @Sarah : By definition of the notion of cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're Welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are assuming that $F(t)=P[X \le t]$ is differentiable, then $F$ is continuous and so $P[t < X < t+\Delta]= P[t < X \le t+\Delta]= F(t+\Delta)-F(t)$ (as long as $\Delta \ge 0$).

(If $\Delta<0$ then $P[t < X < t+\Delta]= 0$.)

Then $\lim_{\Delta \downarrow 0} {P[t < X < t+\Delta] \over \Delta}=\lim_{\Delta \downarrow 0} {F(t+\Delta)-F(t) \over \Delta}=\lim_{\Delta \to 0} {F(t+\Delta)-F(t) \over \Delta} =F'(t)=f(t)$.

Comment: But how to show that $F'(t)=f(t)$? There is no additional condition:$f$ is continuous.

Comment: @mathbeginner I am assuming that it is differentiable. In any event, it is differentiable ae.

Comment: You mean in any event $(\int_{\infty}^x f(t)dt)'=f(x)$?